# How to change endpoint url?

Tags: java, web-services, websphere, jax-ws

I try to deploy my app on websphere 8.5.5.6. If i run my app like

```
public static void main(String [] args){
     Endpoint endpoint = Endpoint.create(new GenericAccountImpl);
     endpoint.publish("http://0.0.0.0:9084/service/GenericAccount")
}
```

it works perfect. But when i try to deploy it on WAS(it hosted at another machine), it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You don't just hard-code the endpoint URL when deploying to an EE app server like WebSphere.

From [the doc](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/uwbs_providehttp.html):

> The actual endpoint URL that is contained in a published WSDL file
>   consists of the prefix followed by the module's context-root and the
>   web service url-pattern, for example,
>   http://myHost:9045/services/myService.

Comment: my wsdl file contains it. But doesn't it still doestn't work. my url in wsdl file is `http://myHost:9084/context-root/services/GenericAccount`.
But it doesn't help me. What could be go wrong?

Comment: Is this Liberty or traditional WebSphere?

Comment: Kurtz, suppose it traditional. in log head `Websphere [IBMJAVA71 7.1.3.10 cf071533.01]Platform 8.5.5.6 [ND 8.5.5.6] running with process name SBT...`